# Computing weak derivative, example 1 Evans PDE.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives

Consider the following problem:
[image]
Thus we have 
$$\int_{0}^{2}u\phi'dx = \int_{0}^{1}x\phi'dx + \int_{1}^{2}\phi'dx$$
$$=-\int_{0}^{1}\phi dx + \underbrace{\phi(2)-\phi(1)}_{\text{why is this }0?} = -\int_{0}^{1}\phi dx = -\int_{0}^{2}v\phi dx.$$
I don't get why the $\int_{1}^{2}\phi'$ is equal to $0.$ Any hints will be much appreciated.

Comment: Note the space that you’re assuming $\phi$ lives in.

Comment: Yeah, I get it now. So I guess in general $\phi$ would vanish at the boundaries of whatever interval we are working on.

Comment: Yes, exactly! $\ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integration by parts in your second equality should read:
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 x\phi'(x) dx + \int_1^2 \phi' dx &= [x\phi(x)]_0^1 - \int_0^1 \phi dx +\phi(2) - \phi(1) \\
&= \phi(1) - \int_0^1 \phi dx + \phi(2) - \phi(1)\\
&=- \int_0^1 \phi dx.
\end{align} 
Observe that $\phi(2)=0$ since $\phi$ belongs to the space $C_0^\infty(0,2)$ and therefore has compact support on $(0,2)$.

Comment: But you still have $\phi(2)-\phi(0)$ left?

Comment: Is it because at the boundaries $\phi$  vanishes as the support of $\phi$ is contained inside the set $(0,2)?$

Comment: Yes, that is why.

Comment: +1 for your answer but it's $0\phi(0)$

Comment: @Isham: Your are right.